# Json Value access in Jquery

Tags: json, ajax

I am getting Json Response from ajax page like this

```
[{"City":"","Email":["khyatiramaswamy9@gmail.com"],"Father\u2019s Name":"Khyati Ramaswamy","Job_Title":[],"Name":"Khyati Ramaswamy","PERSONAL DETAILS":"Khyati Ramaswamy  \n\nSobha Hillview \n\nKanakpura road\n\nBangalore - 560052\n\n+91-9920374975 (M)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\tOBJECTIVE \t\n\n \n\nI seek to give my best on the work front to grow and explore my skills to contribute to the organization that offers professional growth.\n\n\n\n\tWORK EXPERIENCE\t\n\n\n\nDubai4u Investments                                                                                               2019\n\n\n\nSales and Operations  Manager\n\n\n\nResponsibilities \n\n\u2022 Responsible for overall operations of the company\n\n\u2022 Managing Sales Team \n\n\u2022 Managing overall coordination with Clients\n\n.\n\nHop \u2013 Jump \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2004 - 2006\n\n\n\nI started my own business \u2018Hop \u2013 Jump\u2019 a specialist at event planning and organizing\n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nI was the founder of the Company that specialized in customizing parties and events for Clients \n\nI established a strong network with caterers, decorators, anchors, performing artists, party suppliers that could help set up the event as per the specifications and budgets of the client.\n\nWe generated business through word of mouth, partnering with caterers & decorators to generate leads\n\n\n\n\n\nHathway\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2003 - 2004\n\n\n\nWorked a Public Relations Officer  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nUndertook collections and follow up \n\n\n\n\n\nNisus Integrated Marketing Solutions Pvt Ltd. Media\t\t\t\t2000 - 2002\n\n\n\nWorked a Business Development Manager  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nGrow the market for Nisus by working out solutions that establish it as a one destination marketing solutions provider.\n\nDrive not just regular but also new business for Nisus\n\nMarket research to recognize changing requirements and trends to offer better solutions to clients\n\nProactively understanding client requirements and offering integrated marketing solutions \n\nLooking at non convention business opportunities and tapping its potential\n\nEstablish relations with vendors who are more competitive and upbeat\n\n\n\n\n\nNisus Integrated Marketing Solutions Pvt Ltd. Media\t\t\t\t1197 - 1998\n\n\n\nWorked a Sales and development Executive  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nLead Generation and follow up with potential customers to maximize business opportunities\n\nBuild and manage database to pool in more business \n\nTele marketing to establish and sell Nisus\u2019 marketing solutions across media.\n\n\n\n\n\n\tEDUCATION\t\n\n\n\nQualification: \tPostgraduate Diploma in Advertising and Marketing \n\nFrom: \t\tBharti Vidya Bhavan\u2019s Rajendra Prasad Institute of Communication and Management  \t\n\nYear: \t\t2000-2001\n\n\n\nQualification: \tB. Com   \n\nFrom: \t\tNagpur University\t\n\nYear: \t\t1999-2000\n\n \n\n\tINTERESTS \t\n\n\n\nReading \n\nEvents Planning and Organizing\n\nTravelling & backpacking\n\nCooking and Nutrition Planning\n\n\n\n\tPERSONAL DETAILS\t\n\n\n\nDate of Birth: 9th November 1979\n\nGender: Female\n\nMarital Status: Married\n\nLanguages Know: English, Guajarati, Hindi\n\nBasic Skills: Word, Power Point\n\nEmail Address- khyatiramaswamy9@gmail.com","Phone":["+91-9920374975"],"Skill":[],"State":"","colleges":[],"pin_code":"560052","spoken_languages":["English","Hindi"],"universities":[]}]
```

when i can the city value like this -> alert(data.city) it coming like undefined.
Ajax code :

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <span class="pf-title">Resume</span>
                                    <div class="pf-field">
                                       <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" value="" class="resume"/> <?php if($row['Upload_Resume'] == "" || $row['Upload_Resume'] == "NULL") { ?> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 10px;">Update Resume</a>  <?php } else{ ?> <a href="All-resumes/<?php echo $row['Upload_Resume']; ?>" target="blank" class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 10px;" >View Or Download Resume</a><?php } ?>
                                       <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".resume").on('change', function(){
           var name = $("#resume").val();
           var fd = new FormData();
           var files = $('#resume')[0].files;
           if(files.length > 0 ){
           fd.append('file',files[0]);
           $.ajax({
              url: 'get_resume_data.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: fd,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(dataa){
                 var dataVal = JSON.parse( dataa );
                 alert(dataVal);
               alert(dataVal[0].City);
              },
           });
        }else{
           alert("Please select a file.");
        }
        });
     });
```

Ajax Page code:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $files =$filename;
        $postData = curl_file_create(realpath($files),mime_content_type($files),basename($files));
        $data = array('file' => $postData);
    $request = curl_init('');
                curl_setopt_array($request, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                ));
            $result = curl_exec($request);
            curl_close($request);
            echo $result;
```

This is what i have trying to do,Thanks in Advance

Comment: You still would need to `JSON.parse()` the string (character sequence) returned by the ajax call. In this way you can access its properties like any other ordinary Javascript object.

Comment: @mardubbles i tried that it returning [object][object]

Comment: Ok, then it's likely already parsed. ... *Notice* however that your json is an array outermost. So you would need to treat it as such when accessing properties, e.g. `data[0].City`.

Comment: @mardubbles its return undefined now....what to do??

Comment: Make sure you are being *case-sensitive*. The property name is `City` not `city`.

Comment: Since the "C" is capitalized in the property "City", you must also type it that way accordingly.

Comment: i have checked with both city & City,same undefined

Comment: $.ajax({
                  url: 'get_resume_data.php',
                  type: 'post',
                  data: fd,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function(data){
                    alert(data[0].City);
                  },
               });

Comment: Check your browser console at this point (dev tools) for the specific error and line number to commence debugging.

Comment: okey will check that

Comment: Also, apply `data = JSON.parse(data);`  before you do your `alert()`. "data" is probably an ordinary string after all and needs to be parsed into an object from the json def.

Comment: its only alert [object][object] when alert(data),alert(data[0]),but alert(data[0].City) return null value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245316/discussion-between-pk-and-mardubbles).

Answer (score 0):

In comments you mention

> its only alert [object][object] when alert(data),alert(data[0]),but alert(data[0].City) return null value

This is only possible if the sample data you provided in your question is not actually the case (in all scenarios).

However *if* we go by your sample ajax response, we can test it for valid json by directly assigning it to a variable. Note that in your actual code you wouldn't do this, so this ANSWER is to only illustrate that the json in your sample is valid.

```js
let data = [{"City":"Hello","Email":["khyatiramaswamy9@gmail.com"],"Father\u2019s Name":"Khyati Ramaswamy","Job_Title":[],"Name":"Khyati Ramaswamy","PERSONAL DETAILS":"Khyati Ramaswamy  \n\nSobha Hillview \n\nKanakpura road\n\nBangalore - 560052\n\n+91-9920374975 (M)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\tOBJECTIVE \t\n\n \n\nI seek to give my best on the work front to grow and explore my skills to contribute to the organization that offers professional growth.\n\n\n\n\tWORK EXPERIENCE\t\n\n\n\nDubai4u Investments                                                                                               2019\n\n\n\nSales and Operations  Manager\n\n\n\nResponsibilities \n\n\u2022 Responsible for overall operations of the company\n\n\u2022 Managing Sales Team \n\n\u2022 Managing overall coordination with Clients\n\n.\n\nHop \u2013 Jump \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2004 - 2006\n\n\n\nI started my own business \u2018Hop \u2013 Jump\u2019 a specialist at event planning and organizing\n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nI was the founder of the Company that specialized in customizing parties and events for Clients \n\nI established a strong network with caterers, decorators, anchors, performing artists, party suppliers that could help set up the event as per the specifications and budgets of the client.\n\nWe generated business through word of mouth, partnering with caterers & decorators to generate leads\n\n\n\n\n\nHathway\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2003 - 2004\n\n\n\nWorked a Public Relations Officer  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nUndertook collections and follow up \n\n\n\n\n\nNisus Integrated Marketing Solutions Pvt Ltd. Media\t\t\t\t2000 - 2002\n\n\n\nWorked a Business Development Manager  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nGrow the market for Nisus by working out solutions that establish it as a one destination marketing solutions provider.\n\nDrive not just regular but also new business for Nisus\n\nMarket research to recognize changing requirements and trends to offer better solutions to clients\n\nProactively understanding client requirements and offering integrated marketing solutions \n\nLooking at non convention business opportunities and tapping its potential\n\nEstablish relations with vendors who are more competitive and upbeat\n\n\n\n\n\nNisus Integrated Marketing Solutions Pvt Ltd. Media\t\t\t\t1197 - 1998\n\n\n\nWorked a Sales and development Executive  \n\n\n\nResponsibilities\n\n\n\nLead Generation and follow up with potential customers to maximize business opportunities\n\nBuild and manage database to pool in more business \n\nTele marketing to establish and sell Nisus\u2019 marketing solutions across media.\n\n\n\n\n\n\tEDUCATION\t\n\n\n\nQualification: \tPostgraduate Diploma in Advertising and Marketing \n\nFrom: \t\tBharti Vidya Bhavan\u2019s Rajendra Prasad Institute of Communication and Management  \t\n\nYear: \t\t2000-2001\n\n\n\nQualification: \tB. Com   \n\nFrom: \t\tNagpur University\t\n\nYear: \t\t1999-2000\n\n \n\n\tINTERESTS \t\n\n\n\nReading \n\nEvents Planning and Organizing\n\nTravelling & backpacking\n\nCooking and Nutrition Planning\n\n\n\n\tPERSONAL DETAILS\t\n\n\n\nDate of Birth: 9th November 1979\n\nGender: Female\n\nMarital Status: Married\n\nLanguages Know: English, Guajarati, Hindi\n\nBasic Skills: Word, Power Point\n\nEmail Address- khyatiramaswamy9@gmail.com","Phone":["+91-9920374975"],"Skill":[],"State":"","colleges":[],"pin_code":"560052","spoken_languages":["English","Hindi"],"universities":[]}]


alert( data[0].City ); // alerts Hello, not null
```

I only changed the `City` property value of `[0]` to "Hello" as opposed to an empty string. However, even an empty string will not return null.

I didn't want to keep extending comments and provided this answer only to illustrate that *something else* must be wrong with your code that you don't show.

Comment: $.ajax({
                  url: 'get_resume_data.php',
                  type: 'post',
                  data: fd,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function(data){
                     let dataVal = data;
                   alert(dataVal[0].City);
                  },
               });

Comment: Try `let dataVal = JSON.parse( data );`. I mentioned JSON.parse several times already.

Comment: ajax page code - $result = curl_exec($request);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $result;

Comment: i have tried using JSON.parse is only output null in alert

Comment: One of the problems of trying a bunch of different things is that the conversation can get lost. As you can see above, there is zero issue of `alert()` working on parsed json. So *if* your code differs from your question then it would be most helpful if you included your *actual* code in your original question.

Comment: i have updated the code above

Comment: Ok, `get_resume_data.php` may have an error. In your *javascript* ajax success handler, put a `console.log( dataa );` before anything else, and have a look at that result in browser dev tools. Don't know what browser you are using but you can usually open that up with Ctrl+Shift+I, then navigate to Console.